# Create awt and lcdui custom component visual designer plugin for netbeans/eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I'm trying to create an awt and an lcdui custom component visual designer plugin for Eclipse or NetBeans. Drag and drop functionality should be supported.

I have already found this http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaMEComponent_VDComponentProject but I get some errors on the way and cannot complete the whole process described.
Any other links for Netbeans case?

I haven't discovered anything concerning Eclipse. Any links please?

Answer (score 0):

Google donated WindowBuilder pro to Eclipse, and it was available in the Indigo release (June 2010).  See http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/ and [WindowBuilder Pro>Quick Start](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wb.doc.user/html/quick_start.html).

WindowBuilder comes with a set of toolkits already code that can be installed (Swing, SWT, eRCP, GWT).  They are pluggable, so depending on your usecase you might be able to extend one of the existing toolkits or write your own (there must be docs for that somewhere :-)